# How to search query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

The error is that the program fails to search keyword.

Here is the following code:

```
 $query = "SELECT english.word, maranao.word, maranao.pronounciation, maranao.grammar, english.definition" . 
                "FROM english, maranao".
                "WHERE english.keyword_num = maranao.keyword_num and english.word = '$search'";

                $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {   
                    echo $row['word'];
                    echo $row['pronounciation'];
                    echo $row['grammar'];
                    echo $row['definition'];
                }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

You need space in your `WHERE` and `FROM` clause

```
" FROM english, maranao".

" WHERE english.keyword_num = maranao.keyword_num and english.word = '$search'";
```

And don't use mysql [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Try to learn [Prepared statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: this query is space sensitive. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Judo100 if this answer is useful to you don't forget to accept it!!1